# Comparing a string to a user input - Class issue?

Tags: python, class

Okay so i'm having issues with comparing a user inputted value with that already printed into the command line.

The printing to the command line is controlled by the classes that are called and i believe that it's causing issues with the process!

fairly sure i need to use **def** but i'm new to all of this so i don't know where to start!

Thanks for any help ahead of time! Not sure if this is the best way to go about creating a card game as it's pretty convoluted let me know your thoughts!

Originally tried to convert the hand of cards (bob.showHand) into a string but because it's being generated by a class it doesnt work? It's not much code so i've dumped it all below hope that's fine!

```
print('Running')
import random

class Turn:
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start

class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, val):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = val

    def show(self):
        print('{} of {}'.format(self.value, self.suit))

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
         for s in ['Spades', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts']:
            for v in range(1,14):
                self.cards.append(Card(s, v))
    def show(self):
        for c in self.cards:
            c.show()

    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards) - 1, 0, -1):
            r = random.randint(0, i)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[r] = self.cards[r], self.cards[i]
    def drawCard(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.append(deck,drawCard())
        return self
class Player1:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = []


    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())
        return self

    def showHand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()

class Player2:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = []

    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())
        return self
    def showHand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()


print('generating deck')
deck = Deck()

print('shuffling deck')
deck.shuffle()

bob = Player1('bob')
ryan = Player2('ryan')


print('dealing deck')
for x in range(7):
bob.draw(deck)

for y in range(7):
    ryan.draw(deck)

Turn.start = 0
if Turn.start == 0:
    print('bob to act')
    print("bob's hand below")
    print(bob.showHand())

cardplay = input('Type the card to play it')

if cardplay == bob.showHand():
     print('playing card!')
```

I'd expect the print of playing card to appear. However no matter how much i try i can't seem to get it too work!

Comment: You need to make a [mcve], especially including a clear problem statement (see the link under "Describe the problem").

Comment: Think about what (if anything) `bob.showHand()` returns. And keep in mind printing and returning are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `showHand` method does not create a string; it causes `print` to be used to display text in the terminal. `input` reads a string from the user, and stores it. The `==` comparison will never compare equal, because on one side you have a string, and on the other side you have the special value `None`.

You should not have the methods of any of your classes do any `print` calls. Instead, have them `return` the appropriate strings, which are then `print`ed from outside.

Also, by using a special name for these methods - `__str__` - we can make Python use it automatically when `print`ing a class instance, or when converting to string using `str`. Consider the example:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, val):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = val

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.value} of {self.suit}'


class Hand:
    def __init__(self, cards):
        self.cards = cards

    def __str__(self):
        return ' | '.join(str(card) for card in self.cards)


my_hand = Hand([Card('Spades', 'Ace'), Card('Diamonds', 'King')]) # blackjack!
print(my_hand) # we see: `Ace of Spades | King of Diamonds`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `if cardplay == bob.showHand():` does not actually do what you think. `showHand()` returns `None` and that will never equal any input `Card`. You need to convert what the user inputs to a card and then compare that card to the cards the `Player` is currently holding.

To solve these issues and make your code do what you are trying to do, change your `Card` Class to the following:

```py
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, val):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = val

    def show(self):
        print('{} of {}'.format(self.value, self.suit))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if (other.suit == self.suit and other.value == self.value):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

and the last couple of lines to this:

```py
Turn.start = 0
if Turn.start == 0:
    print('bob to act')
    print("bob's hand below")
    bob.showHand()

cardplay = input('Type the card to play it')
picked = Card(cardplay.split()[2], int(cardplay.split()[0]))

for card in bob.hand:
    if picked == card:
        print('playing card!')
```

Then, you can enter any `Card`, **exactly** as it appears, on the input line and it will print

```
'playing card!'
```

Comment: Parsing the input text into a Card instance like this is a good idea, but the way output is done should still be addressed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree with you. I'll leave it to your answer to explain that side however.